# Windows Narrator to read vue.Js application tooltip

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, vue.js

I have a task for windows narrator to read tooltip text. I am using Vue.js for this. Any suggestion for the Narrator to read the tooltip text in the Vue.js application?

```
<div class="Column xs3 md4 lg4 xl4">
   <input class="Input"  id="mnumber" v-on:input="updateValue($event.target.value)" placeholder="@Messages.MPlaceHolder" type="text" v-model="number" />                                         
</div>
<div class="Column xs1 md1 lg1 xl1" style="width:50px">
   <tippy-ext :tippytitle=tippyTitle :tippytext=tippyText ></tippy-ext>
</div>
```

Comment: An a11y (accessibility) issue mainly?

Comment: No, no accessibility issue